# Does anyone know if it is possible to use the Microphone in a custom Keyboard extension in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, microphone, custom-keyboard

Does anyone know if it is possible to 
use the Microphone in a custom Keyboard 
extension in iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

Custom keyboards, like all app extensions in iOS 8.0, have no access to the device microphone, this means that Siri’s dictation speech-to-text functions are not available when you are using a third-party keyboard and also you can’t offer your own third-party dictation functions

see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)